# How to know which form or button is click with flask

Tags: python, html, flask

Hi I'm using flask for the brain of my web page but I have a problem with the shop part, each product has it's own button to add, but when I click one it upgrade all the values but I only wan't to update the one I click.
Can you tell how I can know which button was click with python. Thanks.
Here is my Python code:

```
@app.route("/Menu/<R>", methods = ["GET", "POST"])
def menu(R):
    compra = dict()
    carrito = dict()
    #Making sure that the user has logIn.
    if "user" in session:
        cursor.execute("SELECT ImagenProducto, NombreProducto, PrecioB, Stock, NombreCorto, ProductoId FROM menu inner join menulugar on IdProducto = ProductoId join listalugares on LugarId = IdLugares where Lugar = '{}' Order By IdProducto".format(R))
        menu = cursor.fetchall()
        for x in menu:
            compra[x[4]]=0
        if request.method == "POST":
            for x in compra:
                if x in session.keys():
                    compra[x] = session[x] + int(request.form.get(x))
                else:
                    compra[x] = compra[x] + int(request.form.get(x))
            for x in compra:
                if compra[x]>0:
                    session[x]=compra[x]
            for x in session:
                if session[x] == session["user"]:
                    print('user')
                else:
                    carrito[x] = session[x]
            return render_template("menu.html", menu = menu, name = session["user"], R = R, carrito = carrito)
        else:
            return render_template("menu.html", menu = menu, name = session["user"], R = R, carrito = carrito)
    else:
        return redirect("/LogIn")
```

And this is my HTML code:

```
        <form method="POST">
          {% for x in menu %}
          <div class="AlmacenB">
            <a class="containerB">
                <span class="b-background"><img class="BImg" src="/static/img/Menu/{{x[0]}}"></span>
                <div class="store-infoB">
                  <div class="nombreEspacio">
                    <span class="bName">{{x[1]}}</span>
                  </div>
                    <span class = "Price">${{x[2]}}/Platillo</span>
                    <div class="cantidad">
                      <button class="MoreLess" onclick="deincrement('{{x[4]}}', {{x[3]}}); return false;">-</button>
                      <input class="cantidadAdd" id="{{x[4]}}" name="{{x[4]}}" value="0" readonly></input>
                      <button class="MoreLess" onclick="increment('{{x[4]}}', {{x[3]}}); return false;">+</button>
                    </div>
                    <div class="add">
                      <button class="addB" type="submit">Agregar</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </a> 
          </div>
          <script>
            count['{{x[4]}}'] = 0;
          </script>
          {% endfor %}
        </form>
```

The Script part is only for JS for the button + and - so it dosen't matter

Answer (score 0):

Consider the below situation:

you have multiple `+` buttons, so store the unique value to the `value attribute` of the `button element`.

So button will look like:

```
<button class="btn_add" value="1">+</button>
<button class="btn_add" value="2">+</button>
<button class="btn_add" value="3">+</button>
```

#### JS Code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".btn_add").click(function(){
        clicked_button = $(this).val();
        alert("You clicked button unique id: "+ clicked_button)
        // Your further code here
    });
});
```

So whichever the button you will click, you will get the clicked button value.